# Android Phonegap1.0 usePolling

Tags: android, cordova

I have problem with Android phonegap1.0 
my app was working well but suddenly it prompt usePolling messages
I don't know what I did that cause this message to appear.

Is there any update in that?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code I suspect that the usePolling message appears if the responses from XHR requests to the server start taking too long. It is prompting the end user to use polling so that the requests do not lock up the phone.  This is just a guess.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/blob/master/Android/phonegap-1.0.0.js